# Is Anchore Engine supported to scan vulnerabilities in local Docker image / Private Docker image from DockerHub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-image

I'm using Anchore Engine (not a commercial version) and trying to get it scan over my local Docker image / docker image in my private Docker Hub.

It's following the help from

`INPUT_IMAGE: Input image can be in the following formats:
  registry/repo:tag`

The error message response from running this command
`anchore-cli add private-repo/image-name:tag`

“`Error: cannot fetch image digest/manifest from registry
HTTP Code: 400“`

Could you guys please help in this case ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first add your registry to the anchore engine. Use the following command to add your private registry.

```
anchore-cli registry add <myrepo.example.com:5000> <username> <password>
```

Then use your command to add the repository to anchore.

Anchore has a feature for scanning local images [Anchore Inline Scanning](http://%20https://anchore.com/blog/inline-scanning-with-anchore-engine/). Although I didn't use it personally, looking at the documentation it suggests that the local scan should work.

Answer (score -1):

nowhere in the docker documentation you can find this url `registry-1.docker.io` which is url to all docker images including images in private repositories **in docker hub**. You need to do the following:

1. Add a new registry: `docker-compose exec anchore-engine anchore-cli registry add registry-1.docker.io <your_username> <your_password>`
2. Add a new image `docker-compose exec anchore-engine anchore-cli image add registry-1.docker.io/<repo_name>:<tag>`.